# What is a maximum filter response in MR8 filter bank?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

So I am implementing The Maximum Response (MR) Filter Bank - MR8.
I am using this as a reference:
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/texclass/filters.html

And so far I have written the 38 filters, but have no idea how to compute the maximum filter response from the 6 rotations of each edge and bar filter variations.

1. What is a filter response?
   Is it the result from the filter application or something else?
2. What is a maximum response?
3. How to compute the maximum responses for the edge and bar filters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Suppose you have a filter *`f`* and an image `I`. Filtering `I` with *`f`* is a straightforward convolution of `I` and *`f`*. Let's say the filtered image is *`I_f`*. The response of the filter *`f`* at a pixel `(x,y)` of `I` is then *`I_f`*`(x,y)`.
2. Now, you have a number of oriented filters *`f1`, `f2`, `f3`,* ... Consequently, you will have filtered images *`I_f1`, `I_f2`, `I_f3`,* ... From these you construct a maximum response image *`I_f_max`* as:

   > *`I_f_max(x,y)`* = max (*`I_f1(x,y)`, `I_f2(x,y)`, `I_f3(x,y)`,* ...)

   Therefore, from the application of 6 oriented filters, you have constructed a single response image, which takes into account only the maximum filter response at each pixel and discards the rest.
3. 1 and 2 should answer this.

Comment: Do we have to use gray scale? Or can we use RGB? if yes, how can we choose max?

Answer (score 0):

to answer your follow up question about color images, the VZ classifier stated in https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/texclass/with.html uses grayscale images.

There are however variations which use multichannel/color images, mainly work done by Burghouts and Geusebroek, http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/2006/papers/362.pdf.

This however adds extra complexity and other variations such as incorporating Support Vector Machines (SVM)'s, ('On the Significance of Real-World Conditions for Material Classification', E.Hayman et al.)
can cause larger increases in classification rates while also allowing for a level of scale invariance, one of the main limitations in the 2001 VZ classifier.